# Small GPS device that transmits location to track missing person

Tags: gps

My teenage step-daughter is autistic, and tends to want to run away from school, leisure-club and sometimes even from home. This is very bad for her safety, and a great concern for us.

I am looking for a way to track her, so we can find her again when she runs away.

Here is my ideal (possibly unrealistic) scenario:

- Tiny GPS device with GSM/GPRS
- Can be woken up via sms when needed (so battery will last longer)
- When activated, spins up GPS + Data connection and starts hitting a predefined URL with device ID and long+lat every 15 seconds
- Battery life 7 days on standby (ie. when never activated)
- Can be disabled put back to sleep via sms

I have googled and researched this for a while, but have yet to find a device that fits these requirements.

The solution could also be a mobile phone of some sort, that I can lock down.

Comment: [AT&T FamilyMap][1] looks like it does what you want. Don't lock the phone down too much, you want her to have a reason to carry it. They don't like to admit it, but if you call AT&T customer service they can completely prevent the phone from connecting to the internet while still allowing text messaging (you do loose MMS capability). That's how I have my son's set up. [1]: https://familymap.wireless.att.com/finder-att-family/welcome.htm

Comment: Oops. I see you aren't in the US. Check if your local carriers have something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do most of that with any Android handset using prey

http://preyproject.com/blog/2010/01/prey-arrives-on-mobiles-android-version-available